# Merge multiple SQL Server tables into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

I have many SQL Server tables in a database that have information about the same domain (same columns) and their names are the same plus a date suffix (`yyyyMMdd`):

- TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING_20200131
- TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING_20191231
- TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING_20191130
- TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING_20191031
- TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING_20190930
- TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING_20190831
- ...

This seems like it would make more sense if it was all in the same table. Is there a way, using a query/SSIS or something similar, to merge this tables into one (TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING) with a new column (`extraction_date`) made out of the current table suffix?

Comment: yes. You can write a `INSERT` query to do that. Can you show your attempt ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS with the new table "TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING" as destination and a query that look like this as source:

```
`Select * FROM table1
UNION
Select * FROM table2 
UNION
.
.
.`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SSIS: use union  for the collect data from the multi table and use Derived Column for the extraction_date before the destination for more information you can take from following link:
https://www.tutorialgateway.org/union-all-transformation-in-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
create view v_about_this_thing as
    select convert(date, '20200131') as extraction_date t.*
    from TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING_20200131
    union all
    select convert(date, '20201912') as extraction_date t.*
    from TABLE_ABOUT_THIS_THING_20191231
    union all
    . . .
```

This happens to be a [partitioned view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which has some other benefits.

The challenge is how to keep this up-to-date.  My recommendation is to fix your data processing so all the data goes into a single table.  You can also set up a job that runs once a month and inserts the most recent values into an existing table.

An alternative is to reconstruct the view every month or periodically.  You can do this using a DDL trigger that recreates the view when the new table appears.

Another alternative is to create a year's worth of tables all at once -- but empty -- and to create the view manually once a year.  But a note on your calendar to remind you!

Comment: From now on all the data is going into a single table. My question was about how to deal with the existing tables that were used before today. I'm working on a SSIS package that joins every table and adds it to the final table with the column filled with the correct date coming from the file name. I will post my attempt if I get stuck.

Comment: @danielsto . . . Just insert the data into the existing table.

Comment: That's not the tricky part. I'm having trouble getting a substring of the table name (the date part) inserted into a new column (extraction_date).